Last LibreOffice for a Windows 7 32bits
What is the last version of LibreOffice compatible with Windows7 32bits?
I don't mind about the official release or an unofficial fork.
Other software alternatives are welcome too

This is off-topic for Retro.SE (Windows 7 is too recent; you’re asking about modern software). LibreOffice is supported on 32-bit Windows 7 until at least 25.2 which hasn’t even been released yet!

Windows 7 is just about five years out of support. Anyone using it seriously as their main os is taking risks! Only industrial applications, retro fans, specific gaming fans or people who just don't know how old win7 is would use it. It's on topic to me; I've voted to reopen and your comment is a perfect straightforward answer that answers the question - you should make it an answer.

@knol There is a large degree of subjectivity in what is to be considered "retro" and what is not, different people may draw the lines differently. Is Ubuntu 23.10 retrocomputing? It is out of support, and anyone using it as their main OS is taking risks... Ubuntu 18.10? It's been out of support more than five years... Some pieces of software and hardware get abandoned almost immediately after being released, I don't believe that makes them retro, IMHO that just makes them abandonware.

The help centre says RCSE is for hardware that isn't supported by its manufacturer; and hardware and software in general. I use a semicolon there because they're two separate bullet points, which I can only guess because the page author didn't count old software itself as retro computing for a reason unknown to me. However, I'd like to offer that Windows is so integral to the normal use of computers, and that W7 is -long- unsupported, it's a retro os. In other words, tl;dr, sorry moonwalker and Stephen, W7 -is- the past and we're all old. :)

@knol right, I should have said that the current consensus on Retro.SE is that … As far as I’m concerned, “I consider “retro” as anything that wouldn’t be used for production purposes in most cases; put another way, anything that would in most cases only be used out of curiosity, or to re-live a by-gone era of computing.” That leaves some subjectivity however; the discussion usually hinges on whether Windows 7 is sufficiently different from later, still-supported releases. And who would want to relive Windows 7? ;-)
